# Javascript/jQuery Id check to drive numbering function with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need help with a loop... it's probably simple but I'm having difficulty coding it up.

Basically, I need to check existing Ids for their number so I can create a unique id with a different number. They're named like this: id="poly'+i'" in sequence with my function where i is equal to the number of existing elements. Example: Array 1, Array 2, Array 3 corresponding with i=1 for the creation of Array 1, i=2 for Array 2, etc.

Right now i is based on the total number of existing elements, and my "CreateNew" function is driven off x=i+1 (so the example above, the new element will be named Array 4). The problem is that if you delete one of the middle numbers, the "Create" function will duplicate the high number. i.e. Array 1, 2, 3 delete 2, create new-> Array 1, 3, 3.

I need an if() statement to check if the array already exists then a for() loop to cycle through all i's until it validates. Not sure how to code this up.

The code I'm trying to correct is below (note I did not write this originally, I'm simply trying to correct it with my minimal JS skills):

```
function NewPanel() {


  var i = numberOfPanels.toString();
  var x = (parseInt(i)+1).toString(); 


  $('#items').append('<div onclick="polygonNameSelected(event)" class="polygonName" id="poly'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;Array '+ x +' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removePolygon('+i+');return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>');
  $('div[id*=poly]').removeClass('selected');
  $('#poly'+i).addClass('selected');
  $('#poly'+i).click(function() {
    selectedPolygon = i;
    $('div[id*=poly]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

}
```

THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify "The problem is that if you delete one of the middle numbers, ". What do you mean by delete? Anyway, the simplest solution is to create two arrays. Both arrays will have the same created id's. Whenever an id is created in the first array, an id will be added to the second array. So when it is deleted from first array, check your second array's highest value and then create this id in first array. I hope this did not confuse you.

Comment: There is a separate function on the UI that allows for the user to "delete" the Array. Your solution makes sense, except for the case when you have Array 1 and 2 with [1,2,3,4,5] for example, and remove all but 1 from Array 1. You'll simply be creating an id with value = 5 from array 2 which results in the same id duplication problem.

Comment: Will be testing this out as it is a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is hard to tell why you cannot just splice the array down. It seems to me there is a lot of extra logic involved in the tracking of element numbers. In other words, aside from the index being the same, the ids become the same as well as other attributes due to the overlapping 1, 3, 3 (from the example). If this is not the case then my assumption is incorrect.

Based on that assumption, when I encounter a situation where I want to ensure that the index created will always be an appending one, I usually take the same approach as I would with a database primary key. I set up a field:

```
var primaryKeyAutoInc = 0;
```

And every time I "create" or add an element to the data store (in this case an array) I copy the current value of the key as it's index and then increment the `primaryKeyAutoInc` value. This allows for the guaranteed unique indexing which I am assuming you are going for. Moreover, not only will deletes not affect future data creation, the saved key index can be used as an accessor.

Comment: You're correct in assuming that the ids become the same as well. I'm not familiar with the "key" term and am having difficulty visualizing how I could implement your solution. An additional constraint is that I'm limited on the indexing to i=4, (i=0 - i=4 corresponding to Array 1-5 per the x variable).

Comment: Sorry for my obvious lack of programming knowledge! Trying to learn :) In terms of incrementing your variable, you just do primaryKeyAutoInc++?

Comment: @JohnMitman - If you are limited to only 5 then perhaps there may need to be swapping implemented. I suppose it would depend if you could have only 5 total ever, or 5 total active. As for the `primaryKeyAutoInc++` - **yes**, that is exactly how I do it. Right after I store the value I increment it so that the value stored is guaranteed to be unique.